# How to put buttons on SpriteKit with Swift code?

Tags: swift, xcode7

I tried to make a game on Xcode 7 Beta,  I almost finished it but the problem is I don't know how to put buttons with Swift code, I tried to put them on Main.storyboard but they don't arrange very well. some of them become bigger and  some smaller etc... So I want to know how to put these buttons with code as in picture  below.
Blue button first from the left is Leaderboard, then Facebook share, twitter share, and another default button (maybe it will be Remove Ads)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons should be .png files in the images.xcassets (you can add a new image set by clicking the + at the bottom). It will automatically choose the right size depending on the device/simulator. Then you create a variable to store your node like this:

```
let myNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yourImage")
```

Then you can position the node multiple ways but i'll show you what I think will work best for you. Use `myNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) *0.40, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)` This will get the max x and y values of the screen, multiply them by .4 and .25 respectively and then you can add the node to the scene will this line:

```
self.addChild(myNode)
```

Oh, and you can multiply the values by whatever decimal you want to get the nodes in the exact spot. IF you want them to be side by side you can even do something like this: `myNode.position = CGPointMake(otherNode.position.x + myNode.frame.size.width/2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)`

Comment: this code  'myNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) *0.40, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)' and this ' myNode.position = CGPointMake(otherNode.position.x + myNode.frame.size.width/2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)' won't work found error and said expected declaration, I declared myNode but won't work, weird !

Comment: "Expected declaration" usually appears when you're adding code outside of a function and the code needs to be in the function. Add these lines in didMoveToView @EminEmini

Comment: Ya I did that but it found an error in same code "'*' is not a prefix unary operator"

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do it is because I'm using Xcode 7 Beta, I hope You readed text.